# curl_multi not running second request

Tags: php, curl, response

I'm trying to send data to two different URLs using curl_multi and get an URL from the response of one of the URLs and redirect the user.

So far everything works except the second request is not being processed.

Here is my code:

```
// create both cURL resources
$ch1 = curl_init();
$ch2 = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
//--------------------------CH1
curl_setopt_array($ch1, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://my.crm.com/api/signup",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{"userip":"'.$_REQUEST['ip'].'","firstname":"'.$_REQUEST['firstname'].'", "lastname":"'.$_REQUEST['lastName'].'", "email":"'.$_REQUEST['email'].'", "password":"'.$_REQUEST['password'].'", "phone":"'.$_REQUEST['phonenumber'].'", "prefix":"'.$_REQUEST['phonecode'].'" }', 
)); 
//-------------------------CH2
curl_setopt_array($ch2, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://my2.crm2.com/api/signup",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{"userip":"'.$_REQUEST['ip'].'","firstname":"'.$_REQUEST['firstname'].'", "lastname":"'.$_REQUEST['lastname'].'", "email":"'.$_REQUEST['email'].'", "password":"'.$_REQUEST['password'].'", "phone":"'.$_REQUEST['phonenumber'].'", "prefix":"'.$_REQUEST['phonecode'].'" }', 
)); 

//create the multiple cURL handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();

//add the two handles
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch1);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch2);

// While we're still active, execute curl
$active = null;
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mh == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    // Wait for activity on any curl-connection
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) == -1) {
        continue;
    }

    // Continue to exec until curl is ready to
    // give us more data
    do {
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
    } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
}

//close the handles
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch1);
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch2);
curl_multi_close($mh);

//responses

$response1 = curl_multi_getcontent($ch1);
$response2 = curl_multi_getcontent($ch2);

//read response and redirect
$json_array = json_decode($response1, true);
$loginurl = $json_array['data'];
header("Location: $loginurl");
```

I have tried different solutions but I still cannot get that second request ($ch2) to work.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? I don't see you decoded or `echo` the `$response2`.

Comment: also dont manually build your json payload, you're not escaping or handing types

Comment: Actually I am not using $response2 yet. My mistake. I will echo it and see what is going on with it.

Comment: @CarnageV don't use echo when debugging. use var_dump() - if there was an error in the curl apis, the response may be bool(false), but if there was no curl api error, but the website didn't return a response body, the return may be emptystring, echo will not tell you if you got an empty string, or if you got a bool(false), hence echo may not tell you where the error is, if any, but var_dump() can. Rule of thumb: use var_dump() when debugging, not echo.

Comment: ... what do you think happens if $_REQUEST['password'] contains `"` ?  use json_encode to json-encode strings.

Answer (score 0):

there's several things wrong with your code, but i suspect you dont get content #2 because you close the multi_handle before fetching the results... in fact, i'm surprised you get the first content, even.

but first i want to complain about this:

```
curl_setopt_array($ch1, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "url",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{"userip":"' . $_REQUEST['ip'] . '","firstname":"' . $_REQUEST['firstname'] . '", "lastname":"' . $_REQUEST['lastName'] . '", "email":"' . $_REQUEST['email'] . '", "password":"' . $_REQUEST['password'] . '", "phone":"' . $_REQUEST['phonenumber'] . '", "prefix":"' . $_REQUEST['phonecode'] . '" }',
));
```

1: use CURLOPT_POST, not CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST (for one, it's just the right thing to do, and libcurl actually understands that you want a POST request then, rather than some nonstandard request)

2: what do you think will happen if `$_REQUEST['password']` includes `"` ? it would corrupt your json, making it unparsable...

3: via manipulating $_REQUEST['password'] (or any other variable there), your code is vulnerable to JSON injection, hackers can for example spoof their IP, giving a fake `userip` (if you don't know what JSON injection is, it's kindof like [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), but they can inject JSON data (like a spoofed userip) instead of SQL commands, looks like:  `{"data":"real_data","data":"evil_hacker_injected_version_of_data_that_will_replace_it_because_it_is_the_last_definition_of_data"}`  )

use json_encode() to safely create your json, like this:

```
curl_setopt_array($ch1, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "url",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(array(
        'userip' => (string) $_REQUEST['ip'],
        'firstname' => (string) $_REQUEST['firstname'],
        'lastname' => (string) $_REQUEST['lastName'],
        'email' => (string) $_REQUEST['email'],
        'password' => (string) $_REQUEST['password'],
        'phone' => (string) $_REQUEST['phonenumber'],
        'prefix' => (string) $_REQUEST['phonecode'],
    ))
));
```

... and here

```
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mh == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
```

you're checking the wrong value, $mh is NEVER CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM , you want to compare it to $mrc, not $mh
(also CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM has been removed by the libcurl developers because so many people used it wrong, and that happened years ago, it's no longer needed in modern code.)

in addition to that, i don't like the way you implemented the loop at all.. try this instead:

```
while (1) {
    do {
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
    } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    if (!$active) {
        break;
    }
    curl_multi_select($mh);
}
```

but with all that said, i believe your real problem is that you run curl_multi_remove_handle() & curl_multi_close() BEFORE you call curl_multi_getcontent().